# MySQL.Data issues on Linux in .net Core Application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have installed the nuget for MySQL.Data version 6.10.x and the 8.0.8 DMR each with the same issue.  My interaction with the classes and compilation is fine, however, when I deploy my code to the linux environment I am faced with this error.

```
Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'system.data.sqlclient', version: '4.3.1', path: 'runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard1.3/System.Data.SqlClient.dll'
```

If I go to the directory, the file is in fact there and I don't believe it is permission related as I have chown the file to 777 just to prove it isn't the case.  If I go in the deps.json and remove info related to that assembly, it picks the next in the list forever.

I realize these are beta releases, I am just trying to do some work with MySQL in a linux env and this seems like the best way, however deployment seems to be a challenge.  Any advice / help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: _System.Data.SqlClient.dll_ is the managed provider for Sql Server not for MySql

Comment: Seems to be a required dependency of the MySql.Data nuget package so I assume it is used in some way by it.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a permissions issue.  I had to chmod the directory the dependencies were in to the same group, the executable simply couldn't see the other assembly and thus thought it wasn't there.